# How to check if user input is in lower or uppercase yet still print out an answer

Tags: python, input, capitalization

I am really just starting programming with python and I have a small program that responds to certain user input. I would like to have it so that when you type in something that is capitalized it doesn't matter whether it is capitalized in the code. This is the code I have written so far.

I can't add an image because I don't have enough rep but I think I can explain it.

So this is the code that I have at the moment

Loops and responds to specific user input

```
import random

BOO = ("Aghh!", "That wasn't just a fart!", "Oh, I was soo scared", "I am so terrified       right now", "Where did you spring from?!", "If this was any more scary it would be R  rated!")

x = ""
print "I am a simple computer program designed to respond to certain inputs from a user"

x = raw_input("Input: ")
while not(x == "exit" or x == "Exit"):

    if x == "Oli" or x== "oli" or x == 'Oliver' or x == 'oliver':
        print "Its the creator!"

    elif x == "hi" or x == "hello" or x == "Hi" or x == "Hello":
        print "Hi!"

    elif x == "how are you?" or x == "how are you":
        print "Fine thanks!"


    elif x == "boo!" or x == "boo" or x == "BOO!" or x == "Boo":
        print random.choice(BOO)

    elif x == "You are actually awesome":
        print "Aww, Thanks!"

    else:
        print "Hello, " + x
    x = raw_input("Input: ")
```

For example: On line 21 where the user inputs the word "boo" I have had to add an or statement for the different capitalization of the world. Is there a way that the code can check for capitalization and still print the same output (or randomised)
I have checked over stackoverflow yet I cannot find the answer to my problem. Thankyou.

Comment: Why would you post an image anyway? Post the code! And have a look through http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Comment: You decide whether you're going to deal in uppercase or lowercase in your program and then convert all user input to whatever you've decided.

Comment: Just in case, `x in ['hi', hello']` looks much better. And of course `.lower()` as have said below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly you want the user's input whatever that is to be uppercased
or lowercased respectively so you won't have to check every time the capitalization.

So you could use the upper function or lower function after taking the input from the user:

```
userInput = raw_input("Insert text").upper()
```

or

```
userInput = raw_input("Insert text").lower()
```

If you just want to test whether the input is in capitals or lowercase letters you can import the string module and use the string.ascii_lowercase or string.ascii_uppercase.

```
import string

userInput = raw_input("Insert text")

print userInput in string.ascii_lowercase
print userInput in string.ascii_uppercase
```

Hope that helped :)
Alex

**EDIT:** Right so I believe I got it now! Your issue is that for the input BOO for example you are not sure if the user will type Boo or BOO or boo and so you have to have to check all the possible capitalizations of the user's input. That was basically what I tried to explain in my previously!

What you can do is grab the user's input like that:

```
userInput = raw_input("Insert Text").lower()
```

Now, in whatever capitalization the user enters the word BOO (Boo,BOo,boo,BOO etc...) the variable userInput will in all these cases contain `boo` as we always lowercase the user's input. So instead of checking for example if the user's input is boo or BOO or Boo you just have to check if it equals to `boo` to proceed!

If you want to accept exclamation marks as well though,then you would need to add another check for that as well!

Hope that helped!

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the information. I just added the code that I have into the question, I sort of understand what you are trying to say but I need a little bit more explanation

Comment: More explanation - well, maybe it'll be easier to grasp if you take it in two steps:  
(1) `user_input = raw_input("Input: ")`  
(2) `input_lower = user_input.lower()`
Then you can compare `input_lower` against just the lower-case version of your test strings. You no longer have to care about the casing that the user used.  
You don't even necessarily need a new variable for the lower-cased input: `user_input = user_input.lower()`.  
Or, as Alex suggested, you can get the user input and also lower-case it at the same time: `user_input = raw_input("Input: ").lower()`.

Comment: Maybe the chaining of methods is confusing you.  
You can call `.lower()` on a string, right? Eg. `greeting = "HI"` then `greeting.lower()` *returns* `hi` (without modifying of `greeting` itself).  
(You don't even need a variable: `'HI'.lower()` also returns `hi`, although doing that with string literals is rarely useful.)  
Anyway, `raw_input("Input: ")` returns a string, right?  
So you can call `.lower()` on that return value, without having to put it into a variable first.  
And then the return value of that chain of method calls is the string returned by the last call in the chain.

Comment: Yes, Now I understand Edward, thankyou! This will help greatly wwith the code I am trying to write. I just did not get what the .lower() was doing.

Comment: Not essential, but a nitpick: it's better to use .casefold instead of .lower in such contexts.